# Removendo uma imagem via unlink não funciona

Tags: php, imagem

Eu tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

```
//carrega a imagem anterior
$img = $db->prepare("select ipco_descr_multimidia,ipco_arquivo from ipco_multimida where ipco_id_questao_fk = :id ");
$img->bindParam(':id',$id);

//executa a query
$img->execute();

//recupera os valores da tabela
$resultado = $img->fetchAll();
$caminho = $resultado['ipco_arquivo'];
$nome = $resultado['ipco_descr_multimidia'];

//apagar o arquivo antigo da pasta
if(file_exists($caminho.$nome)) {
    @unlink($caminho.$nome);
    //exit;
}
```

Tabela multimídia:

```
ipco_descr_multimidia | ipco_arquivo
1413297340.jpg        | ./img/upload/
```

Quando executo o código, não apaga a imagem que esta dentro da pasta img/upload.

Comment: Começe removendo o `@` que suprime o erro em `unlink` e talvez você comece a ter mais pistas do que está errado...

Comment: O problema está mais relacionado a remoção do arquivo que do banco de dados. Verifique as permissões da pasta. Coloque o sistema operacional que está usando.

Comment: Resolvido,  faltou adicionar a posição do array $ipco_descr_multimidia = $resultado[0]['ipco_descr_multimidia'];

Comment: Ele está encontrando o arquivo? Ou seja, a instrução `file_exists($caminho.$nome)` está retornando `TRUE`? Pode ser também um problema de localização. Como está sua estrutura de pastas, o arquivo que você está executando está no mesmo local da pasta `img`?

Comment: @hulckb coloque como resposta o procedimento que você executou para resolver o problema.

Comment: **CUIDADO** A função de PHP [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) devolve `TRUE` se o caminho terminar numa diretoria, ou seja, se a variável `$nome` estiver vazia, o código atual entra na mesma no `IF`. Usar a função [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) é a forma mais segura de verifcar se o ficheiro existe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo teu código, existem algumas coisas podem ser melhoradas de forma a existir maior coerência entre o que pretendes e o que estás a fazer. Por outro lado, algumas das sugestões visam resolver potenciais problemas de segurança:

1. Usa a declaração de PDO [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) que te devolve uma linha ao invés da [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

   <sup>*Este ponto resolver o problema que te levou a colocar a pergunta.*</sup>
2. Usa a função [`is_file()`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) para verificar se o ficheiro existe pois a mesma só devolve `TRUE` se existir um ficheiro e for de fato um ficheiro.
3. Verifica os valores antes de os utilizares, como podes ver em baixo fazendo uso da função [`empty()`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
4. Não escondas os erros do sistema, o teu código deve estar preparado para lidar com os mesmos. A função [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) devolve `FALSE` quando algo corre mal. Se algo correu mal, deves agir em conformidade quer informando o utilizador quer tomando medidas alternativas para a tarefa em questão.

**Exemplo do teu código com o descrito em cima:**

```
/* Carrega a imagem anterior
 */
$img = $db->prepare("
  SELECT ipco_descr_multimidia, ipco_arquivo
  FROM ipco_multimida
  WHERE ipco_id_questao_fk = :id
");
$img->bindParam(':id', $id);

// executa a query
$img->execute();

// recupera os valores da tabela
$resultado = $img->fetch();

$caminho = $resultado['ipco_arquivo'];
$nome = $resultado['ipco_descr_multimidia'];

/* apagar o arquivo antigo da pasta
 */
if (!empty($caminho) && !empty($nome) && is_file($caminho.$nome)) {

    if (!unlink($caminho.$nome)) {
      die("Ups... correu mal!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Zuul